# Agora Live Interactive Video Streaming Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Can anyone help me with setting up a basic live stream video on unity with agora, I'm kind of a beginner and the documentation is quite confusing, it doesn't specify where to put certain lines of code whether on Start or Update.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite easy to try out the SDK.  You can just open Asset Store from your Unity Editor, search and find "Agora Video SDK".  Download and import the asset into your project.  You should find a Demo folder where you can start playing with it immediately.  Be sure to read the README files before you start making a build.  For reference, you may check out this blog which shows you the steps too:
https://medium.com/@jake_agora.io/mac-run-video-chat-within-your-unity-application-e001091db62f